# Search Json array inside a col with php sql query

Tags: php, json, mariadb

I need some help please.

Currently my mariadb is set up with one column as a json array.

I would like to search the array from a users input, then combine it with the first and last name of the user stored in the database.

In the database:

Columns: firstname, lastname and suburbs_i_cover (containing the json array)

ex: ["Pretoria","Cape Town","Garden Route"]

I would like the sql statement that would search the suburbs_i_cover and allow me to combine the first and last name.

So far I have this:

```
<?php

//echo JUri::getInstance();

if (isset($_GET['category'])) {
$catetogry = $_GET['category'];
$name = $_GET['name'];

$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query = ("SELECT * FROM #__jsn_users"); //not sure what goes here

$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();


foreach($results as $obj) {

    $value = json_decode($obj->suburbs_i_cover);

    $value = array_filter($value, 'strlen');  //removes null values 
but leaves "0"
    $value = array_filter($value);            //removes all null 
values

    if (!empty($value)) {

    $value2 = $obj->firstname;
    $value3 = $obj->lastname;

    echo $value2 . ' '. $value3;
    //echo "<br>";
   // echo sizeof($value);
    echo "<br>";
    if (is_array($value)) {
        foreach ($value as $sub_value) {
            echo $sub_value;
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }

        echo "<br>";
        echo "<hr>";

} 

}
}
```

Comment: Storing JSON (or other data formats) in a database is *normally* a sign that your data model isn't great. The data isn't normalised, which will mean operations like this, and indexing, are hard and expensive.

Comment: @Utkanos Unfortunately, I have to work with current setup. :(

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using. I ask as MySQL 5.7+ has a JSON data type. Are you using a JSON Datatype?

Comment: What MySql version do you have? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-function-reference.html

Comment: @RiggsFolly 5.5.5-10.0.34-MariaDB-1~jessie

Comment: MariaDB isn't MySQL right? Why not tag MariaDB to get optimal exposure to your question.

Comment: Then I think you are going to have to select ALL the rows and `json_decode()` each rows column and then look for the data you want

Comment: "which will mean operations like this, and indexing, are hard and expensive." @Utkanos Some databases like PostgreSQL allow good and fast indexing on directly  JSON data (JSONB). MySQL also allowes indexes on JSON but on generated columns which works just as fast as a normal index.. JSON (NoSQL) will be properly more developed within databases think off MySQL 8.0 which is a SQL and NoSQL database in one.

Comment: @Script47, updated thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a working solution:

To use: in_array($name, $value)

```
<?php

//echo JUri::getInstance();

if (isset($_GET['category'])) {
$catetogry = $_GET['category'];
$name = $_GET['name'];

$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query = ("SELECT * FROM #__jsn_users");
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();


foreach($results as $obj) {

    $value = json_decode($obj->suburbs_i_cover);

    $value = array_filter($value, 'strlen');  //removes null values 
but leaves "0"
    $value = array_filter($value);            //removes all null 
values

    if (in_array($name, $value)) {

        $value2 = $obj->firstname;
        $value3 = $obj->lastname;

        echo $value2 . ' '. $value3;


        echo "<br>";
        echo "<hr>";


    }

}
}


?>
```

Comment: Selecting all records (the `select * from ..` part) is likely a waste.  You could trim it down by doing `select * from tablename where json_colum rlike 'searchword'` or similar.  Strongly recommend reviewing basic SQL statements...